# PDO with limit and offset not working....so of

Tags: mysql, pdo, limit, offset, using

I am using pagination for my application. I have limit set to 25. For a particular page,  the first page shows 25 records. If I try the subsequent links, I get no results. If I put the numbers into the POD sql statement, it works fine. Heres my code:

```
public function list_all($limit, $offset)
{
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM patients LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset';
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->debugDumpParams();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
}
```

Debugging on the second page renders the following:

```
SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM patients LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset Params: 2 Key: Name: [6] :limit paramno=-1 name=[6] ":limit" is_param=1 param_type=1 Key: Name: [7] :offset paramno=-1 name=[7] ":offset" is_param=1 param_type=1
```

Comment: I tried echoing the values of the passed parameters in the beginning of the function. For the 2nd page I get 25 25
echo $limit; echo $offset:

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

type the parameters

$limit = (int)$limit;
offset = (int)$offset;